# `show create table` equivalent in sap hana

Tags: sql, hana

In MySql you can see the table definition (columns with their data types etc) with show create table table_name.

Is there a similar functionality for SAP HANA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually there are several ways to do that.

1. SAP HANA Studio table editor (open the table definition) and click on the export as SQL icon.
2. call `get_object_definition ('schema_name', '<object_name>')`
3. Use the export table functionality - this will create a .SQL file with the definition.

Comment: can you tell me what happens in the background.like which query will be executed.

Comment: The queries depend on the object type - but basically run along the dictionary tables.

Answer (score 3):

There is no desc table_name in sap hana..

However, you can try this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE_NAME FROM TABLE_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<yourtablename>'
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the sql directly?

Comment: Hana Studio can create the sql for views, but for tables this is not possible at the moment